# How to handle missing Element in XML to CSV conversion?

Tags: python, xml, csv

`"currentAddress"` in the XML below is an optional element. My python code works fine where `"currentAddress"` element is present and errors out if it is missing.

XML:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns2:exportEmpData xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.example.com/">
<emplist>
  <empId>6029</empId>
  <fullName>Justin Clark</fullName>
  <currentAddress houseNumber="14" street="Lepanto" city="Barcelona"/>
</emplist>
<emplist>
  <empId>6078</empId>
  <fullName>Jose Domingo</fullName>
</emplist>
</ns2:exportEmpData>
```

My Python Code:

```
import xml
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('C:/emp/emplist.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# open a file for writing

Emp_data = open('C:/emp/emplist.csv', 'wb')

# create the csv writer object

csvwriter = csv.writer(Emp_data)
emp_head = []

count = 0
for member in root.findall('emplist'):
emp_nodes = []
if count == 0:
    empId = member.find('empId').tag
    emp_head.append(empId)
    fullName = member.find('fullName').tag
    emp_head.append(fullName)
    currentAddress = member.find('currentAddress').tag
    emp_head.append(currentAddress)
    csvwriter.writerow(emp_head)
    count = count + 1

empId = member.find('empId').text
emp_nodes.append(empId)
fullName = member.find('fullName').text
emp_nodes.append(fullName)
currentAddress = member.find('currentAddress').attrib.get('city')
emp_nodes.append(currentAddress)
csvwriter.writerow(emp_nodes)
Emp_data.close()
```

Error Message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'
```

I would like to add a string (eg: `"Unknown"`) if `"currentAddress"` element is not available for an employee.

Comment: Your for and if statement are in the same indentation level, please fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "pythonic" way to handle would be to use `try`/`except` as shown below. This will handle the case when `"currentAddress"` isn't present as well as when it is, but has no `city` attribute.

Note that I also removed the code in the `for` dealing with the `count` variable because it isn't necessary—there's no reason to handle the first one differently that I can see. However there was the need, then the code handling it would also need to do something similar.

```
import csv
import xml
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml_filename = 'emplist.xml'
csv_filename = 'emplist.csv'

tree = ET.parse(xml_filename)
root = tree.getroot()

with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='') as Emp_data:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(Emp_data)

    emp_head = []
    for member in root.findall('emplist'):
        emp_nodes = []

        empId = member.find('empId').text
        emp_nodes.append(empId)
        fullName = member.find('fullName').text
        emp_nodes.append(fullName)

        try:
             currentAddress = member.find('currentAddress').attrib.get('city')
        except AttributeError:
            currentAddress = 'Unknown'

        emp_nodes.append(currentAddress)
        csvwriter.writerow(emp_nodes)
```

Comment: Thank you both martineau and Bill M.

Answer (score -1):

One way you could do this is first see if `member.find('currentAddress')` returns `None`.  If so, just make the city 'Unknown'.  If not, then use `address_tag.attrib.get('city')` to extract the city.  You could additionally put in a check to see that 'city' is one of the existing attributes.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

myxml = """<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns2:exportEmpData xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.example.com/">
<emplist>
  <empId>6029</empId>
  <fullName>Justin Clark</fullName>
  <currentAddress houseNumber="14" street="Lepanto" city="Barcelona"/>
</emplist>
<emplist>
  <empId>6078</empId>
  <fullName>Jose Domingo</fullName>
</emplist>
</ns2:exportEmpData>
"""

tree = ElementTree.ElementTree(ElementTree.fromstring(myxml))

for member in tree.findall('emplist'):
    city = 'Unknown' # Default value if we don't find a city
    address_tag = member.find('currentAddress')
    if address_tag is not None:
        city = address_tag.attrib.get('city')
    print("City is %s" % city)
```